# How to create single row from multiple row?

Tags: postgresql

I have written a SQL with CASE statement in SELECT, which is creating different columns. And my query output is comping in multiple rows (Please refer attached picture of output).

[image]

But I want my output in single row like this:
[image]

Please let me know how can I achieve this is SQL. I am using PostgreSQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT {columns without nulls}, MAX({columns with nulls})
FROM table
GROUP BY {columns without nulls}
```

Of course you must use separate expression for each separate column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.